# xsltproc pre appending <?xml version="1.0"?>

Tags: xslt

All of my output has `<?xml version="1.0"?>` in front of my intended output. How do I get rid of this? I have looked at different flags but I can't find anything relating to this.

Some extra details:

- Using fedora 8
- [a@...]$ xsltproc -V
- Using libxml 20702, libxslt 10120 and libexslt 813
- xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20702, libxslt 10120 and libexslt 813
- libxslt 10120 was compiled against libxml 20702
- libexslt 813 was compiled against libxml 20702

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is an attribute on xslt:output called "omit-xml-declaration"

For example:

```
<xsl:output method="html" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
```

That should remove it.

Comment: I'm giving you the best answer for giving me an example to follow.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, it's `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` in `<xsl:output />`.

Comment: heh, if we're here for races, there should be also time since opening the page ;-)